# svg fill url not working in any Chrome Extension pages but working on any websites and local files

Tags: svg, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on my Chrome Extension:zzllrr Imager Geek and find svg fill url not working in any Chrome Extension pages (URLs start with chrome-extension://).

But on normal webpages(http:,https:, file://.) it works like a charm. Below is the code:

```
<svg id="LRectSq30821072" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="position: absolute; left: 66px; top: 155px; width: 76px; height: 76px; z-index: 2001; filter: none; transform: none;"> 
<defs> 
<linearGradient id="LRectSq30821072linearfill" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%"> 
<stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#3f377d;stop-opacity:1"></stop> 
<stop offset="34%" style="stop-color:#da310a;stop-opacity:1"></stop> 
<stop offset="68%" style="stop-color:#cd2c78;stop-opacity:1"></stop> 
<stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#82a462;stop-opacity:1"></stop> 
</linearGradient> 
</defs> 
<rect x="1" y="1" width="74" height="74" stroke-width="2" stroke="#585c1a" stroke-opacity="1" fill="url(#LRectSq30821072linearfill)" fill-opacity="1" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter"></rect> 
</svg>
```

Comment: What if you set an absolute URI? (`chrome-extension://current-location#the-id-of-your-element`). Chrome always had issues with realtive urls in svg and the what they are relative to... But it might not be it here, maybe rather a protocol issue, so you might also want to double check where your element is rendered (i.e what's their `ownerDocument.location.href` is). Could also be an entirely other bug, and in any way, you may want to fill a bug report to them.

Comment: Thanks. But I've tried the absolute URI and the bug is still there.